# snmpbulkget is giving values of next oid instead of giving the oid mentioned in the argument. Why?

Tags: net-snmp

I thought snmpbulkget acts like snmpget except that it can support multiple oid requests. But I see weird behavior. It gives next OID info instead of what is asked:

```
snmpbulkget -Cr1 servername IF-MIB::ifSpeed.7.0 IF-MIB::ifInOctets.7 IF-MIB::ifInUcastPkts.7 IF-MIB::ifInNUcastPkts.7 IF-MIB::ifInNUcastPkts.7 IF-MIB::ifInDiscards.7 IF-MIB::ifInErrors.7 IF-MIB::ifOutOctets.7 IF-MIB::ifOutUcastPkts.7 IF-MIB::ifOutNUcastPkts.7 IF-MIB::ifOutDiscards.7 IF-MIB::ifOutErrors.7
IF-MIB::ifSpeed.8 = Gauge32: 10000000
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.8 = Counter32: 3674120514
IF-MIB::ifInUcastPkts.8 = Counter32: 2462391943
IF-MIB::ifInNUcastPkts.8 = Counter32: 19169575
IF-MIB::ifInNUcastPkts.8 = Counter32: 19169575
IF-MIB::ifInDiscards.8 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifInErrors.8 = Counter32: 775777
IF-MIB::ifOutOctets.8 = Counter32: 3824588280
IF-MIB::ifOutUcastPkts.8 = Counter32: 2866781089
IF-MIB::ifOutNUcastPkts.8 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifOutDiscards.8 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifOutErrors.8 = Counter32: 0
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`snmpget` will send a single packet containing several OIDs (you can verify this using the `-d` option). So changing your command to use `snmpget` (and removing the `-Cr1` option) will do what you want.

Alternatively you could BULKGET `IF-MIB::ifEntry` which gives you more than you want.

`snmpbulkget` (or rather the underlying GETBULK/GETNEXT) methods always return the **next** variable in the tree.

Quoting from http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/GETBULK ...

> The GETNEXT command (GetnextRequest) requests a list of instances from
>   a remote entity, but expects the next variable in the tree back.